# How we can get language template in mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki

I am studying mediawiki, but i don't know how to translate created and existing pages. I have search in internet some others told like, give the syntax {{languages}} in your page, but i couldn't get Language template in wiki page, i don't know anyone help for me. How to translate the wiki page. Please any one give the instruction step-by-step for this.

Comment: Have you looked into the Template:Language you found?

Comment: I don't know either but here's a good place to start: [{{Language}}](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Language).

Comment: did you ask on irc #mediawiki . You can get answers there much faster

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you are asking for, but did you check [the Translate extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aTranslate)?